# AngularJS で query string を取得する方法

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS で以下のような URL になってしまった際に query string (`key=value`) を取得するスマートな方法はありますか？

`'http://example.com/?key=value#/users/123'`

`$location.search()` では `#` をうまく解釈するようにできているせいか、期待通りには取得できませんでした。素の `location.search` を使うのが良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://example.com/#/users/123?key=value
```

のように `#` より後にクエリを持ってくることで、`$location.search()` がオブジェクト `{key: value}` を返します。

質問にある `http://example.com/?key=value#/users/123` という形式でないとダメな場合は素の `location` を使うしかないかと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

`$location.search()` で `#` より後の `?key=value` が取れることは認識しています。

今回は query string がついた URL をルートとして AngularJS が処理を開始してしまうケースだったので……。

やはり `location` を使おうと思います。